# Adding char into char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I need to add char into char array. This is my code:

```
#define BUFFSIZE  1024
char *first_name[][BUFFSIZE];
char *last_name[][BUFFSIZE];

int j = 0;
first_name[][j] = "John";
last_name[][j] = "Doe";
```

Is this the  right way to enter "John" and "Doe" in the zero th position of the respective arrays?

Comment: Read up on `strcpy` and also perhaps you need `char first_name[BUFFSIZE];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration

```
char *first_name[][BUFSIZE];
```

declares a 2-dimensional array of pointers. If you want an array of strings, it should be:

```
char first_name[][BUFSIZE];
```

However, this is missing the first dimension's size. Omitting the size is only permitted in function argument declarations, because it's actually a shorthand for declaring a pointer (since passing an array to a function decays to a pointer) or in the declaration of a flexible array member (which must be the last member of a `struct`, so you can't have two of them in the same structure). I'm guessing your variables are actually function parameters.

You can't use assignment to fill in a string in C, you have to use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(first_name[i], "John");
```

Comment: I tried doing this. But the array is not retaining its values. The first_name is inside a for loop and the value seems to change for first_name[0] after 3rd or 4th iteration.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ShishirShetty Post the MCVE in the question, not an external site.